# How do I make a method declared as a class extension in an objective c Pods file accessible in my swift project?

Tags: swift, objective-c, cocoapods

[image]

How do I make the tagLabels property, which is declared as a class extension in an objective c .m file installed using Pods, accessible in my swift project? I tried changing the property declaration location from the .m file to the .h file to access it in my swift file, but I had no luck.

Edit: I've done some additional research regarding this issue, and I realized that any changes to an imported module through pod install should be done to a forked repository. However, I still don't know how I could make the tagLabels property accessible in my swift file and whether simply moving the declaration to the .h file will resolve the issue if I edit a forked repository. I would greatly appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Don't show a picture of your screen. Code is text. Copy and paste the text into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Swift can only see Objective C declarations in *header* files that it imports. Your picture is not showing a header file. So Swift cannot see any of it.

Comment: Thank you. I've also tried moving the property tagLabels into the header file, TTGTextTagCollectionView.h, but even after moving the property there, I wasn't able to find it in my swift project.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, forking a repo is for preventing losing all the changes when doing pod update, but editing the source code, .h and .m files should still be allowed. However, when I either move the tagLabels property to the TTGTextTagCollectionView.h file or create my custom properties in the header file, they are still inaccessible.

Comment: If I want to use the edited version of a pod module, should I first fork the repository, install it using pods and reinstall it every time I change the module?